# Missing/misplaced FROM when storing table in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

When I run this query:

```
//---------- Load Claims data ----------
//Let ClaimsPath = '..\..\..\ConsCare\Claims\*.XLSX';
Let ClaimsPath = '\\xx.xx.xx.xx\reports\Claim validation\reporting\Claim files\*.XLSX';
for each File in filelist (ClaimsPath)

Claims:
LOAD
Date(FileTime()) as [Reporting Date],
FileName() as [Source_File_Claim],
*
FROM $(File)
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Data);

next File

//---------- Store and Drop Table ----------

for i = 0 to NoOfTables() - 1
LET d = TableName(i);
store $(d) into $(vDataDir)\$(d).QVD;
next

LET j = NoOfTables();

do while j > 0
let d = TableName(0);
drop table $(d);
let j = NoOfTables();
loop
```

I get this error:

> Syntax error, missing/misplaced FROM: store Claims-1 into
>   \xx.xx.xx.xx\reports\Claim
>   validation\reporting\Qlikviewvalidation\QVD\Claims-1.QVD

I am a newbie to QlikView. Can someone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this message is because of third line in the below:

```
for i = 0 to NoOfTables() - 1
LET d = TableName(i);
store $(d) into $(vDataDir)\$(d).QVD;
next
```

When it tries to evaluate `Claims-1` using $(d), it does so literally and QlikView interprets it as a subtraction (i.e. `Claims - 1`) because it is not enclosed in square brackets. As a result QliKView does not understand the operation and fails.

Therefore, please try changing the above slightly to:

```
for i = 0 to NoOfTables() - 1
LET d = TableName(i);
store [$(d)] into [$(vDataDir)\$(d).QVD];
next
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer buddy. That error is gone. I am accepting your answer and upvoting it..